# AutoMoq to respect MaxLengthAttribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture, castle-dynamicproxy, automoq

I'm using **AutoFixture** with **AutoMoq** to generate and configure a **Mock to an interface**. This interface uses the `MaxLength` attribute to specify the maximum length each property.

How can I make the generated mock respect the `MaxLength` attribute.

Please, consider that I have load of properties using this attribute? (not only one, like in this example).

The code to create the mock is this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true });
var my = fixture.Create<IMyClass>();
```

where MyClass is:

```
public interface IMyClass() 
{
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ... 
    ... more properties using the MaxLenght attribute
    ...
}
```

I have tried making a Custom Specimen builder like this:

```
public class MaxLenghtSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;

        if (pi == null || pi.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }

        var maxLengthAttribute = (MaxLengthAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));

        if (maxLengthAttribute != null)
        {
            return new ConstrainedStringGenerator().Create(new ConstrainedStringRequest(maxLengthAttribute.Length), context);
        }

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }
}
```

in order to add it to the fixture with calling `fixture.Customizations.Add(new MaxLenghtSpecimenBuilder());`

But it doesn't work. It doesn't get the custom attribute. It always returns null.

Comment: Already answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1019).

Comment: From the example code, it looks like `IMyClass` models what DDD would label an *Entity*. Why isn't that a class? How many production implementations of that interface exists?